# JavaScript: text to appear both before hover and after hover.

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can write some JavaScript code more succinctly i.e. without having to write the html again?

Would it be feasible to add any sort of 'id'or 'div' so it shows the text instead rewriting the whole text again?

The last line of my code is:

```
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = image.style.background = "text to appear both before hover and after hover.";
```

My full code is on CodePen:http://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/GrJYLo

Comment: As of now, your code doesn't seem to work. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry I was tring to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign your text to the variable, and then innerHTML it on the start using name of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a simple variable (e.g. `txt`).  This way, the text will remain saved, even if it is removed from the element.